# The best WPF4 Project on CodePlex.com

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend, wpf-4.0

I'm learning this days about WPF and the amazing tool from Microsoft wich named  "Expression Blend 4". It makes our work easier than ever to design our WPF and Silverlight apps,Particularly impressive to me is the SketchFlow feature, which enables rapid prototyping for our WPF and Silverlight applications.Meanwhile the ability to creat rich web experiences, games, desktop apps, and more.

When i Was seaching for samples or examples for a great WPF project on the web, I found some apps like

- [Using the WPF Visualizer to debug applications in Visual Studio 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20150810005306/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/habibh/archive/2009/06/01/using-the-wpf-visualizer-to-debug-applications-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
- [Introducing photoSuru: Feature Overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20121022171530/http://windowsclient.net:80/wpf/starter-kits/introducing-photosuru.aspx)

but they are not avaible to download ,such as payante libraries like Devexpress,Infragistrics and more ..

I'm searching for first exemplar for WPF on CodePlex, to not only learn WPF  but also to learn good practices for enterprise application development across the board.

I searched here in StackOverFlow in therecent topics ,they are talking about the old generation of the WPF , ... WPF4 is amazing !

Comment: I'm searching for the best WPF Projects on CodePlex.com ,or on the web for the inspiration or to read their code .

Comment: you will want to turn it into a wiki and rephrase it as a question before ome overzelous admin type comes along and votes to close.

Comment: I hardly think it's overzealous to want real questions instead of discussion.  It has been stated many times that SO is not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

you can download and try the WPF Application Frameworks and Guidance that are available with its source code and samples on codeplex.com, as stated in the previous answers PRISM and WAF are very helpful and have very powerful samples.

you can also try the following frameworks:

1. [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)

> Caliburn.Micro is a small, yet powerful framework, designed for
>   building applications across all Xaml Platforms. With strong support
>   for MVVM and other proven UI patterns, Caliburn.Micro will enable you
>   to build your solution quickly, without the need to sacrifice code
>   quality or testability.

1. [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

> The MVVM Light Toolkit is a set of components helping people to get
>   started in the Model - View - ViewModel pattern in Silverlight and
>   WPF. It is a light and pragmatic framework that contains only the
>   essential components needed.

1. [Cinch](http://cinch.codeplex.com/)

> Cinch is a fully featured WPF MVVM framework that makes it easier to
>   develop rich MVVM WPF applications. It also provides UI
>   services/threading/unit tests helpers and much more. Cinch is a WPF
>   ModelView-ViewModel framework that takes the UI services route to
>   provide a rich WPF MVVM framework that comes with several standard
>   services out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You should download [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) and look into stock trader reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find the sample applications of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** useful.